# Terraform, AWS and STS The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, terraform, token

I'm trying to use terraform to initiate connections with AWS to create infra.
If I run up aws configure sso, i can log in default to eu-west-2 and move around the estate
I then use terraform apply, with the aws part as follows:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  profile = "450694575897_ProdPS-SuperUsers"
}
```

Terraform reports: Error: error using credentials to get account ID: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
│   status code: 403, request id: 5b8be53d-253d-4c48-8568-ad78be14115f

The following vars are set:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

If I run

```
aws sts get-session-token --region=us-west-2
```

I get

```
An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the GetSessionToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Comment: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY does not make sense to set with AWS SSO. With AWS SSO, you fetch credentials with `aws sso login` and it's stored in a json file. The only thing you should need to set in terraform is region and profile.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I do aws sso login, then I try the same thing: aws sts get-session-token --region=us-west-2    . Same problem. What next

Comment: After clearing vars, then I have in my .tf -------- provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  profile = "450694575897_ProdPS-SuperUsers"
}.       Then run terraform apply, and I get <Code>ExpiredToken</Code> <Message>The security token included in the request is expired</Message>.  Also same error if I remove the shared_credentials_file bit @jordanm.   If I remove the "profile" from the aws section i get a message: The security token included in the request is invalid"   When i run terraform apply

Comment: I've got it to go a lot further, if I do cat ~/.aws/config.  I can see my actual profile name is this : [profile ProdPS-SuperUsers-450694575897]. So then I configure the .tf with provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"
  profile = "ProdPS-SuperUsers-450694575897"
}.  And then I run terraform plan. Runs for ages then eventually says : Error: No valid credential sources found for AWS Provider.

Answer (score 0):

> I was having the same problem when i tried to deploy through `terraform cloud`.

You might be using an `old key` that is either `deleted` or `inactive`, to be sure:

1- Try to go to the security credentials on your account page: Click on your name in the top right corner -> `My security credentials`.

2- Check if the key you set in your credentials is deleted or still exists.

2.2- if it's deleted create a new key and use it.

3- If your key is still there, check if it is `active`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue doing the following:

```
$: aws configure
enter the access key:
enter the secret key:
select default region:
select default format[none/json]:
```

In your main.tf file add the profile shown as below

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-west-2"
  profile="xxxuuzzz"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 - the key was to use the "SSO configure profile legacy mode"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-legacy.html

1. I upgraded aws-cli: `aws-cli/2.11.8 Python/3.11.2 Linux/5.4.0-42-generic exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off``
2. I upgraded terraform: `Terraform v1.4.4`
3. Omitted the SSO session name!!: using legacy format (e.g. without an SSO session)

```bash
    $ aws configure sso --profile default
    SSO session name (Recommended):
    WARNING: Configuring using legacy format (e.g. without an SSO session).
    Consider re-running "configure sso" command and providing a session name.

    SSO start URL [None]: https://yourstuff.awsapps.com/start

    SSO region [None]: <your-sso-region>
    Attempting to automatically open the SSO authorization page in your default browser.
    If the browser does not open or you wish to use a different device to authorize this request, open the following URL:
    
    https://device.sso.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
    
    Then enter the code:
    XXX
```

And terraform worked with

```
variable "awsprofile" {
  type = string
  default = "default"
}

variable "region" {
  type = string
  default = "eu-central-1"
}


variable "keyname" {
  type = string
  default = "frankfurt"
}



terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = format("%s", var.awsprofile)
  region  = format("%s", var.region)
}
```